# css absolute vertical center with pixel offset

Tags: html, css

I have a page with a fixed background image. The page has 3 absolutely positioned divs set to a blend mode. On top of those 3 divs (for the content) I am floating 3 more identical divs but without a blend mode or background color. I want to have those divs in order, one at the top one in the middle and one on the bottom.
I've tried using margin-top to offset the height of the divs but this leaves everything a little too far away from the top to look vertically centered anymore. It's close but not close enough!

The issue with blend modes means I can't set a parent div to control the position of the children as the blend mode is then lost. I tried looking for a solution to the parent situation with the blending mode but can't seem to find anything solid.

Is there a way around this?

**Here's my HTML:**

```
<img src='http://www.pptback.com/uploads/blue-world-map-backgrounds-powerpoint.jpg' alt='background' id='bg' class='noselect' />
<div class='top-bg'></div>
<div class='main-bg'></div>
<div class='foot-bg'></div>
<div class='top-content'>This is the top</div>
<div class='main-content'>This is the main content</div>
<div class='foot-content'>This is the foot</div>
```

**Here's my CSS**:

```
 #bg {position:fixed; min-height:100%; min-width:100%; top:0; left:0;}
.noselect {-webkit-touch-callout:none; -webkit-user-select:none; -khtml-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select:none; user-select:none;}

.top-bg {position:absolute; width:40%; height:60px; top:50%; left:50%; transform:translate(-50%,-50%); margin-top:-185px; background:#393939; mix-blend-mode:multiply; z-index:2;}
.main-bg {position:absolute; width:40%; height:430px; top:50%; left:50%; transform:translate(-50%,-50%); margin-top:61px; background:#515151; mix-blend-mode:multiply; z-index:2;}
.foot-bg {position:absolute; width:40%; height:60px; top:50%; left:50%; transform:translate(-50%,-50%); margin-top:306px; background:#393939; mix-blend-mode:multiply; z-index:2;}

.top-content {position:absolute; width:40%; height:60px; top:50%; left:50%; transform:translate(-50%,-50%); margin-top:-185px; color:#fff; z-index:3;}
.main-content {position:absolute; width:40%; height:430px; top:50%; left:50%; transform:translate(-50%,-50%); margin-top:61px; color:#fff; z-index:3;}
.foot-content {position:absolute; width:40%; height:60px; top:50%; left:50%; transform:translate(-50%,-50%); margin-top:306px; color:#fff; z-index:3;}
```

**Fiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/c0noL31w/

Comment: The problem is the group with the blending modes: a parent div has to carry the blending mode as the children lose the effect. This won't work with the rest of the code I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.
I played around with the numbers and added the height of the top div to the minus offset in my first post, the middle with no offset and the bottom div at the same offset as the top but a positive height and it works perfectly.

HTML

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<img src='http://www.pptback.com/uploads/blue-world-map-backgrounds-powerpoint.jpg' alt='background' id='bg' class='noselect' />
<div class='top-bg'></div>
<div class='main-bg'></div>
<div class='foot-bg'></div>
<div class='top-content'>This is the top</div>
<div class='main-content'>This is the main content</div>
<div class='foot-content'>This is the foot</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#bg {position:fixed; min-height:100%; min-width:100%; top:0; left:0;}
.noselect {-webkit-touch-callout:none; -webkit-user-select:none; -khtml-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select:none; user-select:none;}
.top-bg {position:absolute; width:40%; height:60px; top:50%; left:50%; transform:translate(-50%,-50%); margin-top:-246px; background:#393939; mix-blend-mode:multiply; z-index:2;}
.main-bg {position:absolute; width:40%; height:430px; top:50%; left:50%; transform:translate(-50%,-50%); background:#515151; mix-blend-mode:multiply; z-index:2;}
.foot-bg {position:absolute; width:40%; height:60px; top:50%; left:50%; transform:translate(-50%,-50%); margin-top:246px; background:#393939; mix-blend-mode:multiply; z-index:2;}
.top-content {position:absolute; width:40%; height:60px; top:50%; left:50%; transform:translate(-50%,-50%); margin-top:-246px; color:#fff; z-index:3;}
.main-content {position:absolute; width:40%; height:430px; top:50%; left:50%; transform:translate(-50%,-50%); color:#fff; z-index:3;}
.foot-content {position:absolute; width:40%; height:60px; top:50%; left:50%; transform:translate(-50%,-50%); margin-top:246px; color:#fff; z-index:3;}
```

**New fiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/jrox275g/